# No keyboard works

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem a friend is having. Her keyboard suddenly stopped working. She had a wireless keyboard/mouse combo and the mouse still worked.
She tried with a different usb keyboard, and it still didn't work. She tried with a PS/2 keyboard and it didn't work.

She's running Windows 7, but the keyboard also doesn't work during boot-up.

I've got no idea what could possibly be the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried the original keyboard on another computer?  just to prove the keyboards themselves aren't the problem here.

Comment: What's the BIOS/What model PC is it? Is it a custom built? Is it a pre-built? If it's a custom built, what is the Motherboard Manufacturer?

Comment: It's now fixed. There was a bit of miscommunication between the two of us, she didn't try a second USB keyboard, only a PS/2 keyboard without rebooting and it didn't work. I told her to try the PS/2 keyboard again and reboot, and it worked. It seems that the USB keyboard was broken.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PS/2 Keyboards, you must reboot the computer after you plug them in to get them to work.

They are not designed to be '[hot pluggable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector)'.

Comment: I quote: "She tried with a different ***usb*** keyboard, and it still didn't work.", "She's running Windows 7, but the keyboard also doesn't work during ***boot-up***." Which leads me to the conclusion she has already tried rebooting! ;) Your answer checks out though!

Comment: this isn't really true anymore with most motherboards.  if the BIOS detects a keyboard at the ps/2 port at boot, it puts power to that port, otherwise the port remains powered down.  if you've booted with a ps/2 keyboard plugged in, you can hotswap them all day long.  if you didn't boot that way, you do (probably) need to reboot to get the ps/2 port turned on.  not all motherboards work exactly like that; i have one old P2 system that always turns on the ps/2 port at boot, so hotswapping ps/2 is always possible.

Comment: sorry I didn't update, but problem was solved and that was actually the the issue :) I misunderstood, she didn't try it with a usb keyboard, just a ps/2 one and she didn't know she had to reboot :)

Comment: @Quack Do you have any sources for your information? Everything I've dealt with (I'm a DIY'er with building gaming rigs as far back as the mid-90s) suggests they aren't hot swappable or pluggable.

Comment: @George - I have to say that on newer mobos, I've had success hot plugging PS/2 keyboards even when only USB was attached at boot.  In the early days, that definitely didn't work.  A couple years back though, someone said "hey, why do you shutdown/reboot when you do that?", and I tried without and it worked fine...  Still a good idea though, the PS/2 bus really wasn't designed with hotplug in mind...  :-)

Comment: @george: mostly direct experience, which goes back a little further than yours.  don't remember where i read about BIOS detection determining power to the port, sorry.  they're not designed to be hotpluggable, no; but they've been modernized a little in the 20+ years they've been around.  wikipedia brings up a good point about drivers and such; i don't know if i've ever tried testing out the hotplugging by swapping in radically different keyboards.